# compare a row with a file

Tags: c#, csv, compare

I want to make a compare procedure in my code that takes a text file that has names (one under the other) and compares them with a row of names.

For example : row_example row is:

```
 george
 nick
 gregory
 samantha
```

And the input file with the names (names.txt) is :

```
micheal
john
george
mary
jennifer
oliver 
jack
 harry 
alfie
```

The program will take the first one given from the text file(micheal) and search the row. After will take the next name from the text file given(john) and search the row. etc... etc.. 
It will print a message with the names of the row that where not found.

Comment: Homework? Why didn't you try to solve it and post your code, or if you tried why didn't you post it.

Comment: I would suggest the [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#except1) method from Linq. But the solution is rather trivial.

Comment: @ivan I would have placed my code, but it was in infancy stage.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
private string Compare()
    {
        string[] compareAgainst = File.ReadAllLines("[file_path]");
        string[] row = new string[] { "name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", };
        string result = string.Empty;
        foreach(string name in compareAgainst)
        {
            if (row.Contains(name))
                result = String.Format(result + " {0}", name);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

[file_path] - path to text file containing names, one in each line
Simply print out the result of this method.

Hope this gives you an idea,

Kris